# Nodes not responding to touch

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let locale = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = self.atPoint(locale)
        if playIcon.contains(locale) {
            print("play music")
            musicGamePlayer.play()
        }
        if node.name == pauseIcon.name{
            print("pause music")
            musicGamePlayer.pause()
        }
        if node.name == pauseGameB.name {
            print("is touched")
            self.isPaused = true
            repeatSkull.speed = 0
            loseTimer.invalidate()
        }
        if node.name == playGameB.name{
            print("game play")
            self.isPaused = false
            repeatSkull.speed = 1
            loseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(addTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }


    }
}
```

Would someone be able to explain to me why my nodes have stopped responding to touches . I have tried to check for whether my node's name is equal to another and if a node such as playIcon contains the location , but to no avail (the isUserInteractionEnabled is also set to true)

(UPDATE)

```
//bg
    bg.zPosition = 0
    bg.setScale(1.25)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(bg) 

//play icon
    playIcon.zPosition = 450
    playIcon.name = "play button"
    playIcon.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: -180)
    playIcon.setScale(0.75)
    self.addChild(playIcon)

    //pauseIcon
    pauseIcon.zPosition = 450
    pauseIcon.name = "pause button"
    pauseIcon.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: -180)
    pauseIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pauseIcon.setScale(0.75)
    self.addChild(pauseIcon)

    //playButton
    pauseGameB.zPosition = 450
    pauseGameB.name = "pause game"
    pauseGameB.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150)
    pauseGameB.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pauseGameB.setScale(0.9)
    self.addChild(pauseGameB)

    //pauseButton
    playGameB.zPosition = 450
    playGameB.name = "play game"
    playGameB.position = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 155)
    playGameB.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    playGameB.setScale(0.9)
    self.addChild(playGameB)
```

I understand that my bg node is the parent and should have a zPosition of 0 , but from reading im confused on what my own nodes should be relative to (in the article the child nodes are relative to the helicopter height).

(I tried to make my nodes relative tot the height of my bg node but my playcIcon node is still the only one that registers any touch  )

UPDATE 
I would like to thank Alessandro Ornano for his comment as it did answer my question

"Ok, I've understand your issue, remove all the lines where you set isUserInteractionEnabled == true because by default they should be false and the current scene can intercept touches above them, otherwise you ask to return the touches to each single object bypassing the scene" – Alessandro Ornano

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your ***playIcon, pauseIcon, pauseGameB, playGameB*** all are **SKSpriteNode** objects. use below code to solve your problem:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     for touch in touches{
        let locale = touch.location(in: self)

        if playIcon.contains(locale) {
        print("play music")
        }
        if pauseIcon.contains(locale){
        print("pause music")
        }
        if pauseGameB.contains(locale) {
        print("game B paused")
        }
        if playGameB.contains(locale){
        print("game play")
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried originally but only the playIcon node seems to respond to touch

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a problem related to the `zPosition` of your nodes. **The `print` command below in the code should be help you to understand what node is involved to the touching process**.

If you are not familiar with [`zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483107-zposition) , you can also take a look to the official doc "[Understanding the Drawing Order for a Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html)"

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   let touch = touches.first!
   let location = touch.location(in: self)
   let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)
   print(touchedNode) // debug information about your touched node
   switch touchedNode.name {
   case "pauseIcon"?: 
      // do something
   case "pauseGameB"?: 
      // do something
   default:break
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing a switch case based of the node's name , but again it is only my playIcon that registers any touch

Comment: So your playicon button override the other in term of size, can you see the other buttons? Can you give more informations about your buttons dimensions? –

Comment: Those specific nodes are png images that are 200px by 200px

Comment: Ok, I've understand your issue, remove all the lines where you set  `isUserInteractionEnabled == true` because by default they should be false and the current scene can intercept touches above them, otherwise you ask to return the touches to each single object bypassing the scene

Comment: That worked Thank you !!! , but could you elaborate more on why the touches were intercepted I thought enabling user Interaction would allow touches to be registered

Comment: From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode?language=objc): "..for a node to be considered during hit-testing, its userInteractionEnabled property must be set to YES. The default value is NO for any node except a scene node. A node that wants to receive events needs to implement the appropriate responder methods from its parent class .."